# Binomial distribution exact

Tags: probability, statistics, solution-verification, binomial-distribution

From a box containing 20 balls, 14 of them black and 6 white, we are drawing four balls with replacements. What is the probability, that black ball will be drawn twice?

is my solution right?

$n = 4, k = 2, p = 7/10$

using the formula:

[image]

i got $P(X = 2) = 0,2646$

Comment: yes it is true..

Comment: In R statistical software, where `dbinom` is a binomal PDF, code `dbinom(2,4,7/10)` returns $0.2646.$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct, since replacement is allowed, each draw can be viewed as iid Bernoulli trial with probability of success $0.7$. The number of black balls out of $4$ trials is then $Bin(4, 0.7)$.

$$\binom{4}{2}(0.7)^2(0.3)^2=6(0.21)^2=6\left(\frac{21}{100} \right)^2=\frac{2646}{10000}$$